# Require status memo when work order status changes to a specific status (but not yet saved)

Tags: maximo

Currently using Maximo 7.6.0.8 on Oracle 12c (WAS 8.5.5.11). We have a special synonym to the CLOSE status that I want to use. Whenever the user changes the work order status to this status, I want to require the Memo field.

[image]

There is a [blog post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a/entry/Automation_Script_How_to_make_memo_field_required_depending_on_status_to_be_changed?lang=en) detailing how to do this via an automation script, but I can't get it to work as it is written.

Has anyone gotten it to work? I've tried variations such as changing WOSTATUS to WOCHANGESTATUS...

[image]

I've also turned on DEBUG autoscript logging, but I don't know how to debug the automation script or what I should be looking for. The script doesn't generate any error, but it also doesn't require the MEMO field as required when the status changes to a new status (not saved to database yet).

Comment: Did you try using a Data Restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following script if the status I want to require MEMO on is NOTFAC. I was also able to configure a variation of this using Conditional Expression UI.

```
if vSTATUS == "NOTFAC":
   vMEMO_required = True
else :
   vMEMO_required = False
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Preacher. I figured out another way to do the same thing.

WOCHANGESTATUS is a special non-persistent object that lets you process values that are not saved to the database yet. For example, STATUS that are you going to change work order to, can be manipulated.

In this case, the MEMO attribute is REQUIRED when status = 'NOTFAC'. wochangestatus.status is the new status the work order is going to be selected without being saved yet.

[image]

[image]